# Is there any way to get the state of a bare metal server?

Tags: networking

Is there any way to find out whether a bared metal server divested of any software is turned on or off?

I mean if the sever is not connected to any high level software, like the virtualization hypervisors etc., can we still remotely find out if it is turned on or not and have a status of its state? The only way I could come up with was using ILO but not every client permits you to use it.

I was wondering if there is even any device for it?

Comment: What about a simple `ping`? A server is usually always connected to a network

Comment: Are you talking about a specific brand/make of bare metal server?    The general answer is you need a BMC (base management controller) or similar.  Different brands have different BMC's - IPMI (supermicro, Intel and probably others),  ILO (HP), IDRAC (Dell) are the ones I know of.

Answer (score 1):

This is what "Lights-Out Management" (LOM), including "Integrated Lights-Out" (ILO) features built into server hardware is for.

If you want something similar in an external device, you could look at PDUs, UPSes, and KVMs. Smart PDUs and UPSes will let you see the power draw of a given outlet and switch outlets on and off remotely. Some fancy KVMs allow you to VNC into the KVM (or use a web browser in lieu of a VNC client) and use the attached machines that way, which would even let you remotely watch/control the boot process of the attached systems, so you could even remotely interrupt boot and mess with BIOS/CMOS/EFI/GRUB etc.

There are also "terminal servers" that connect to the serial console ports of devices, allowing you to SSH to the terminal server and it's almost as good as being directly connected to the serial console port of the target device.

Note: By "KVM" in this Answer, I mean a "Keyboard/Video/Mouse" switcher box. Not a "Kernel Virtual Machine".